# Calculating $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+x\cdot \sin x}{-1+\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Without L'Hopital,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+x\cdot \sin x}{-1+\cos x}$$

That's

$$\frac{x^2+x\cdot \sin x}{-1+\left(1-2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\right)} = \frac{x^2+x\cdot \sin x}{-2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}$$

Let's split this

$$\frac{x\cdot x}{-2\cdot\sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot \sin\frac{x}{2}} + \frac{x\cdot \sin x}{-2\cdot\sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot \sin\frac{x}{2}}$$

On the left one, it would be great to have $\frac{x}{2} \cdot \frac{x}{2}$. To do so, I will multiply and divide by $\frac{1}{4}$:

$$\frac{\frac{x}{2}\cdot \frac{x}{2}}{\frac{1}{4}\cdot-2\cdot\sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot \sin\frac{x}{2}} + \frac{x\cdot \sin x}{-2\cdot\sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot \sin\frac{x}{2}}$$

Then we use the identity $\frac{x}{\sin x} = 1$:

$$-2 + \frac{x\cdot \sin x}{-2\cdot\sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot \sin\frac{x}{2}}$$

On the right side, I'd like to have $\frac{x}{2}$ there, so I will multiply and divide by $\frac{1}{2}$:

$$-2 + \frac{\frac{x}{2}\cdot \sin x}{-2\cdot\sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot \sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}$$

We use the identity $\frac{x}{\sin x} = 1$:

$$-2 + \frac{\sin x}{-2\cdot\sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}$$

Hmm... we could perform the addition I suppose:

$$\frac{\sin x - 2(-2\cdot\sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2})}{-2\cdot\sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}$$

Simplify:

$$\frac{\sin x + (4\cdot-2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot-2\frac{1}{2})}{-2\cdot\sin\frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{\sin x +8\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}$$

Then

$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin\frac{x}{2}} + \frac{8\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\sin\frac{x}{2}} = \frac{\sin x}{\sin\frac{x}{2}} + 8$$

I'm close! The answer should be $-4$, but I don't know what to do with

$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin\frac{x}{2}} + 8$$

So basically I need to know what to do with $\frac{\sin x}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}$, but I also included my whole procedure just in case I've been doing it wrong all along.

Comment: Hint:$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin\frac x2}=2\Bigl(\frac{\sin x}x\Big/\frac{\sin\frac x2}{\frac x2}\Bigr)\ .$$

Comment: Woah, hold on.  The denominator goes to $0$, no matter how how much you mess with it.  Why not use L'Hopital?

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese for learning purposes I am supposed to be able to do this without L'Hopital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $$\lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{x^2+x\sin x}{-1+\cos x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{x^2+x\sin x}{-1+1-2\sin ^2\frac{x}{2}}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\sin x+x^2}{\sin ^2\frac{x}{2}}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}+1\right)}{\sin ^2\frac{x}{2}}$$

$$=-2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x}+1}{\left(\frac{\sin \frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}}\right)^2}$$
$$=-2\left(\frac{1+1}{1^2}\right)=-2(2)=\color{red}{-4}$$

Comment: How did you get rid of the $x^2$ from $x^2\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}+1\right)$, and how did you divide $\left(\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\right)$ by $\frac{x}{2}$ near the end?

Comment: OK, just take $x^2$ common from $x\sin x+x^2$ to get $x^2\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}+1\right)$  then re-write $x^2$ as $$x^2=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2}$$

Comment: Well that's a surprisingly clever way (to me) to approach this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simpler approach is as follows
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{2} + x\sin x}{-1 + \cos x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{2} + x\sin x}{-1 + \cos x}\cdot\frac{1 + \cos x}{1 + \cos x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{2} + x\sin x}{-1 + \cos^{2} x}\cdot(1 + \cos x)\notag\\
&= -2\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{2} + x\sin x}{\sin^{2} x}\notag\\
&= -2\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{x^{2}}{\sin^{2}x} + \frac{x}{\sin x}\right)\notag\\
&= -2(1 + 1) = -4\notag
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You did this in a needlessly elaborate way.

$$\frac{x^{2}+x\sin x}{-1+\cos x}\approx\frac{x^{2}+x\left(x-x^{3}/6\right)}{-1+\left(1-x^{2}/2\right)}=\frac{2x^{2}-x^{4}/6}{-x^{2}/2}=-4$$